# Building a Docker Image with rstan on rocker/verse

Tags: docker, clang, rstudio, rstan

I am planning to run a customized Rstudio with both `tidyverse`, `rmarkdown`  and `rstan` pre-installed on Digital Ocean's `Docker 17.03.0-ce on 16.04`.

On Docker Hub, there is already a pre-built image: `Rocker/verse` that has `tidyverse` and `rmarkdown` functionality. So my plan was to simply get the latest version of `Rocker/verse` and add a new layer of `rstan`. I use the dockerfile of [jonzelner/rstan](https://hub.docker.com/r/jrnold/rstan/) and [jrnold/rstan](https://hub.docker.com/r/jrnold/rstan/) and update them as below:

```
FROM rocker/verse:latest

# Install essentials
RUN apt-get update \ 
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
                   clang-3.6

# Global site-wide config
RUN mkdir -p $HOME/.R/ \
    && echo "\nCXX=clang++ -ftemplate-depth-256\n" >> $HOME/.R/Makevars \
    && echo "CC=clang\n" >> $HOME/.R/Makevars

# Install rstan
RUN install2.r --error \
    inline \
    RcppEigen \
    StanHeaders \
    rstan \
    KernSmooth

# Config for rstudio user
RUN mkdir -p /home/rstudio/.R/ \
    && echo "\nCXX=clang++ -ftemplate-depth-256\n" >> /home/rstudio/.R/Makevars \
    && echo "CC=clang\n" >> /home/rstudio/.R/Makevars \
    && echo "CXXFLAGS=-O3\n" >> /home/rstudio/.R/Makevars \
    && echo "\nrstan::rstan_options(auto_write = TRUE)" >> /home/rstudio/.Rprofile \
    && echo "options(mc.cores = parallel::detectCores())" >> /home/rstudio/.Rprofile

# Install loo
RUN install2.r --error \
    matrixStats \
    loo
```

However, my attempt to build this image (`docker build -t image_name .`) ended in error. The results are provided below:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.56 kB
Step 1/6 : FROM rocker/verse:latest
 ---> 7ad7d994bffd
Step 2/6 : RUN apt-get update   && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends                    clang-3.6
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 77473c759438
Step 3/6 : RUN mkdir -p $HOME/.R/     && echo "\nCXX=clang++ -ftemplate-depth-256\n" >> $HOME/.R/Makevars     && echo "CC=clang\n" >> $HOME/.R/Makevars
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a5b06d28b9fe
Step 4/6 : RUN install2.r --error     inline     RcppEigen     StanHeaders     rstan     KernSmooth
 ---> Running in 86b52d5a76f3
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/inline_0.3.14.tar.gz'
Content type 'unknown' length 18002 bytes (17 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 17 KB

* installing *source* package ‘inline’ ...
** package ‘inline’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (inline)

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/downloaded_packages’
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/RcppEigen_0.3.2.9.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'unknown' length 1209128 bytes (1.2 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.2 MB

* installing *source* package ‘RcppEigen’ ...
** package ‘RcppEigen’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
clang++ -ftemplate-depth-256 -I/usr/local/lib/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"  -I../inst/include -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c RcppEigen.cpp -o RcppEigen.o
/bin/bash: clang++: command not found
/usr/local/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:141: recipe for target 'RcppEigen.o' failed
make: *** [RcppEigen.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RcppEigen’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RcppEigen’
Error in install.packages(pkgs = f, lib = lib, repos = if (isMatchingFile(f)) NULL else rep,  :
  installation of package ‘RcppEigen’ had non-zero exit status
The command '/bin/sh -c install2.r --error     inline     RcppEigen     StanHeaders     rstan     KernSmooth' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Some similar questions about a package having `non-zero exit status` have to do with memory, so I tried to increase the Docker memory on my local machine, but still no luck. Is there any thing I can do to successfully build this image?

Answer (score 0):

As you see in the error output, the installation process cannot find the compiler:

```
/bin/bash: clang++: command not found
```

Be aware that this is the output from trying to install `clang-3.6` in a `rocker/verse` container:

```
root@8ea0d98e67c3:/# apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends clang-3.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'python-clang-3.6' for regex 'clang-3.6'
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
```

It appears that this image doesn't come with Clang 3.6 in its repositories. And this name instead points to `python-clang-3.6`; Clang bindings for the Python programming language.

Unless you absolutely want 3.6, I would install the plain `clang` package that points to 3.5, and then re-run the Docker build process.

```
apt-get install clang
```